# Drupal6 - Display specific View from a specific user in page

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I need a help displaying a specific View result in a page which the user created it.

story...
"User X has created a Page called My Store and UserX has products which was created in custom Content Item."

Now how do I show this UserX's products in his My Store page?

I have already made a view called User_Store_View, I added a Page Display and on Page Settings:Path, the value was "node/%".. now I guess my problem is on the Arguments?

Answer (score 0):

The path should be something like `my-store` and it should have an argument of `user id`. Given your requirements I think setting the default behaviour for the argument being invalid or not being supplied to an empty result set would be the most sensible(I think the default is show all). That may be all you really need.

However, if your product is a type that you've created yourself you will need to do some behind the scenes wiring to expose all your fields to Views; it's almost always better to build a content type using CCK so it's already hooked up to Views. And D7 is a different beast in this regard, with fields part of core and whatnot, so I can't help you out there.

Comment: will the above work if I have thousands of users(I call them Store)?

Comment: oh and the "My Store" page was "node/5"

Comment: what should set on "Page: Configure Argument User: Uid" ?

Comment: Ok, I've got a clearer understanding now. You've got a page to which you're trying to add a view by giving it the same URL as the page... that's not going to work unfortunately. Mixing views and nodes is a little tricky, I'll think some more about it.

Comment: oooooh thanks a lot!! did you know that it took my whole afternoon making that thing work.. thew view shows up, when there's no Arguments added..

Comment: hey @CurtainDog. Am watching this http://gotdrupal.com/videos/drupal-views-arguments